# Abbreviations inside in-text citations

Tags: abbreviations, citation, mla

I'm using an in-text citation in my paper which is as follows:

> Our case studies demonstrate that NGET have already provided a wide
>   range of environmental, security, health and safety, and economic
>   benefits

Unfortunately the reader will not understand what an NGET is unless I can explain it. What would be the proper way to showcase what this abbreviation stands for in an mla-style paper?

Comment: Do you mean that the text you've included is a direct quotation, which you will follow with an in-text citation?

Answer (score 1):

Spell out abbreviations or acronyms before their initial use, and include the preferred abbreviation in parentheses after the term.

> Our case studies demonstrate that Next Generation Economic Technology (NGET) have already provided a wide range of environmental, security, health and safety, and economic benefits.